# AVAudioRecorder delegate not assigned in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, avaudiorecorder

I decided to rewrote audiorecorder class from Objective C to Swift.
In `Objective C` recording works, but in `Swift` `AVAudioRecorderDelegate` delegate methods not called, recorder starts successfully.

How can I fix this?

```
class VoiceRecorder: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        var error: NSError?

        let audioRecordingURL = self.audioRecordingPath()
        audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioRecordingURL,
            settings: self.audioRecordingSettings(),
            error: &error)

        audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
        /* Prepare the recorder and then start the recording */
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        if audioRecorder.prepareToRecord(){
            println("Successfully prepared for record.")
        }
    }

    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder!, successfully flag: Bool) {
        println("stop")
        if flag{
            println("Successfully stopped the audio recording process")
            if completionHandler != nil {
                completionHandler(success: flag)
            }
        } else {
            println("Stopping the audio recording failed")
        }
    }
}

func record(){
    audioRecorder.record()
}

//UPD.
func stop(#completion:StopCompletionHandler){
    self.completionHandler = completion
    self.audioRecorder?.stop
}
```

Comment: Code looks OK. Why do you expect delegate method to be called? It is called when you stop - but I don't see a stop method... How do you stop it, and what actually happens when you do?

Comment: @matt I call audioRecorder.stop() to finish recording.

Comment: And what happens? Nothing at all in the log?

Comment: Can you show the code that says `stop()`?

Comment: @matt Please see updated code at the bottom.

Comment: But that's not a call to the `stop()` method. You're just saying the name of the function. That's the problem; you're not actually stopping.

Comment: @matt It's called, I checked in the log. I also added stop part from view controller.

Comment: Dude I'm looking right at your code. I can see that you're not calling `stop()`.

Comment: @matt Sorry, I thought you're talking about another thing. Thank you so much!

Comment: You would think the compiler would at least warn you: "This is not actually a method call. Are you sure you don't want to add some parentheses?" :) Sometimes it does, but I guess not in this situation.

Comment: @matt That's the problem — in this particular case I have no warnings at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
self.audioRecorder?.stop
```

That is not a call to the `stop` method. It merely mentions the name of the method. You want to say this:

```
self.audioRecorder?.stop()
```

Those parentheses make all the difference.